# MAUI: Windows platform can't access location

Tags: maui, winui-3

the microsoft document says that accessing location doesn't need permission in windows platform

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows

However,my program got an error

```
Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.PermissionException: You need to declare the capability `location` in your AppxManifest.xml file
   at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions.BasePlatformPermission.EnsureDeclared()
   at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions.LocationWhenInUse.CheckStatusAsync()
   at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions.EnsureGrantedAsync[TPermission]()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.GeolocationImplementation.GetLocationAsync(GeolocationRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at PowerSaver.MainPage.GetCurrentLocation()
```

I use the example form official one,though.

```
_isCheckingLocation = true;

GeolocationRequest request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

_cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

if (location != null)
      Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
```

System details:

```
Version Windows 11 professional workstation Insider Preview
Edition 22H2
System edition  25236.1010
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.25236.1010.0
```

sorry for my poor english & thank you

how can I fix the permission error?

Comment: I created a plain MAUI app project, replaced the contents inside the boiler-plate ``OnCounterClicked()`` with your code, run the app, clicked the button but seems to work fine. BTW, in my Package.appxmanifest file, there is <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" /> by default.

Comment: Maybe I didn't grant the permission in setting for the application

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code you provided and also meet the question that Windows platform can't access location.

But I solved this issue. In Windows 11, in Location privacy settings my Location services wasn't on. So, I turned it on, and now it is working.

In addition, if you also want to run it on Android platform, remember to add this to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me exactly as the error stated, `You need to declare the capability` location `in your AppxManifest.xml file`, you need to literally declare location in the `AppxManifest.xml` file:

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Or using VS UI

[image]